# Python sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, summarization

I am new to Text Processing with Python.In the following code TfidfTransformer is used to compute the a normalised matrix for a given document (only one document). My question is how is the idf value calculated when no background or corpus has been specified? I understand that to calculate idf we require a collection of documents.

```
sentences = sentence_tokenizer.tokenize(input)
temporary = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(sentences)
normalized_matrix = TfidfTransformer().fit_transform(temporary)
```

Comment: I think the `idf` part is just 1 when you have only one document. This is computed as: `log(n / df(d, t)) + 1`. With one document, `n` and `df(d, t)` are both 1. So, `tf-idf` just gets reduced to the term frequency.

Comment: So that means it is only normalizing using term frequency and not by tf-idf. This makes sense but scikit document is not very helpful in justifing this clearly.

Comment: I think that is correct. It should be very easy to verify as well.